# How to assert process.stderr output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, io, tdd

I'm building a little command line tool and I hit a problem with testing.

How can test that the current process wrote "omg" in `stderr`?

```
process.stderr.write("omg")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install Mocha if you haven't:

```
npm install -g mocha
```

**shouldpass.js:**

```
process.stderr.write('omg')
```

**shouldfail.js:**

```
process.stdout.write('not omg on stderr')
```

**test.js:**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
  , assert = require('assert')

describe('run tests', function(){
  it('should pass', function(done) {
    exec('node ./shouldpass.js', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      assert.equal(stderr, 'omg')
      done()    
    })
  })

  it('should fail', function(done) {
    exec('node ./shouldfail.js', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      assert.equal(stderr, 'omg')
      done()    
    })
  })    
})
```

To run:

```
mocha test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary overwrite the `process.stdout.write`, buffer the input and use `console.error` to print the output (`console.log` will not work when `process.stdout.write` is overwritten), e.g.

```js
describe('process.stdout', () => {
    let processStdoutWrite,
        processStdoutWriteBuffer,
        overwriteProcessStdoutWrite,
        resetProcessStdoudWrite,
        getProcessStdoutBuffer;

    /**
     * @var {function} Reference to the original process.stdout.write function.
     */
    processStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;

    /**
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    overwriteProcessStdoutWrite = () => {
        processStdoutWriteBuffer = '';

        process.stdout.write = (text) => {
            processStdoutWriteBuffer += text;
        };
    };

    /**
     * @returns {string}
     */
    getProcessStdoutBuffer = () => {
        return processStdoutWriteBuffer;
    };

    /**
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    resetProcessStdoudWrite = () => {
        process.stdout.write = processStdoutWrite;
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        overwriteProcessStdoutWrite();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        resetProcessStdoudWrite();
    });

    describe('.write()', () => {
        it('prints "foo"', () => {
            process.stdout.write('foo');
            process.stdout.write('bar');

            console.error(getProcessStdoutBuffer());
        });
    });
});
```